# KERAS ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WJN9p.png)

Could you please help me fixing this error 
here is the entire code 
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12qDK5LunQG_adU61sBVYS2mOgKcEOFY2
thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please include the code and all relevant information in the question itself, instead of linking to external page. This helps keep it useful for future readers.

Comment: Learn [how to use code block](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Can you please print out the type, shape, etc. of "x_train=np.array(x_train)" ?